# How do i prevent lilo from doing a disk scan?

Tags: linux, raid, gentoo, mdadm, lilo

I have gentoo installed using root on LVM on RAID5.  I made a mistake when I set up lilo but the initrd created by genkernel caught it and allowed me to type in the correct root partition.  I have modified the lilo.conf, but when i try to install the adjusted boot menu I get

```
...
Reading boot sector from /dev/sda
Fatal: Incompatible Raid version information on /dev/md0   (RV=0.90 GAI=1.2)
```

Now I know I installed lilo from the install CD earlier, so somehow it was able to get past this fatal error earlier.

What do I need to add to the lilo.conf to tell lilo to ignore that RAID partition?  My initrd takes care of all the wackiness for me, so I don't need lilo's too-clever-by-half RAID logic.

Comment: Did you create your raid with mdadm metadata = 1.2 ? I believe lilo uses metadata 0.9. I'm not sure why I got one of my machines to work with 1.2 though.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have worked around the problem by booting from the install CD and re-running lilo **without /proc/ mounted** inside the chroot.  This gives me a

```
Warning: '/proc/partitions' does not exist, disc scan bypassed
```

This is probably how I got it installed before.  I do not consider this a proper answer to my question because it requires me to unmount /proc (which seems dangerous for a running system, and I don't want to have to reboot to a rescue/install CD every time I want to update my lilo).

The true solution to this question will be a way to make lilo work even if /proc/partitions is available.